# Map over two arrays of objects, match properties and store specific info in a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototypejs, array.prototype.map

New to javascript and trying to learn! I am trying to map through two array of objects, and if a certain property matches, pull in specific information into an array.

```
let result;

let arrNames = [{
  name: "A"
}, {
  name: "B"
}, {
  name: "C"
}]

let arrInfo = [{
  name: "A",
  info: "AAA"
}, {
  name: "B",
  info: "BBB"
}, {
  name: "C",
  info: "ccc"
}]
```

If arrNames.name == arrInfo.name, I would like result to equal arrInfo.info.

What I've tried:

```
arrNames.map(x => {
if(arrNames.name == arrInfo.name){
   result=arrInfo.info
}
```

^ This obviously doesn't work -- but I'm wondering if Assign or Filter would be appropriate.

Thanks in advance for your help (apologies that this is probably a dupe)!

Comment: Don't modify the question  when existing answers address your original question. Ask a new question instead (I see that you already did). Rolling back to previous version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) inside [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to find the element. This finds the element even if they aren't at the same index in both arrays.

Then use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter any `undefined` values which will be present if there isn't a match.

```js
var arrNames = [
   {name: "A"},
   {name: "B"},
   {name: "C"}
];

var arrInfo = [
   {name: "A", info: "AAA"},
   {name: "B", info: "BBB"},
   {name: "C", info: "ccc"}
];

let result = arrNames.map(x => {
  item = arrInfo.find(item => item.name === x.name);
  if (item) { 
    return item.info;
  }      
}).filter(item => item !== undefined); // Can also use filter(item => item);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = [];

arrNames = [
   {name: "A"},
   {name: "B"},
   {name: "C"},
]

arrInfo = [
   {name: "A", info: "AAA"},
   {name: "B", info: "BBB"},
   {name: "C", info: "ccc"},
]

result = arrNames.map(function(_, index){
  if(arrNames[index].name === arrInfo[index].name) {
    return arrInfo[index].info
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map with a condition inside

```
el.name === arrNames[index].name && el.info
```

Means:

```
if (el.name === arrNames[index].name) return el.info
```

```js
let arrNames = [{
  name: "A"
}, {
  name: "B"
}, {
  name: "C"
}]

let arrInfo = [{
  name: "A",
  info: "AAA"
}, {
  name: "B",
  info: "BBB"
}, {
  name: "C",
  info: "ccc"
}]


const res = arrInfo.map((el, index) => el.name === arrNames[index].name && el.info)

console.log(res)
```